# Azure Staged deployment : Entity Framework Code First Migrations not executed of swap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have noticed that when I swap the staging and production slots, the EF migrations do not get run on the production slot.

I have one context/db for ASP.NET Identity and another one for my application data. The ASP.NET Identity context uses a CreateIfNotExist initializer and I can see that the corresponding DB gets correctly created on production. However my application context uses the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer coming with migrations, and it looks like it is not automatically triggered when I swap the environments on Azure.

There is a checkbox “Execute Code First Migrations” when using Web Deploy from Visual Studio, but as it can be expected they only run on the stating slot which is where I deploy the app. I need the migrations to be executed on the production environment too after a swap. How can I handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [MSDN Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx) which describes how to use code first migration deployment on Azure. The checkbox 'Execute Code First Migrations' manipulates the web.config file to update the database. However, when you swap stages, the web.config is not swapped.

You should use the 'App_Start code' solution, then the migrations will run also on the production slot.

Comment: I don't believe this solves the problem. When swapping, the web server is already running and does not run App_Start again.

Comment: But the website is restarted automatically after swap.

Comment: Are you sure? How does swapping "warm up the web server" if it is restarted? Do you have any documentation that clarifies this?

Comment: It worked for me. However I do not find a document which defines this. I think when the connection string changes while swapping, the app will have to be restarted, but if the connection string (and other settings) stay the same maybe it won't.

Comment: that makes sense if the connections string changes then the app does an automatic restart. I was wondering how my app would function correctly if that were not the case. It seems that behavior has been occurring for me because I do see down time during a swap.

I wonder if the setting that is applied to the web.config that causes an automatic migration is also swapped and will run against the production database also.